# Pyspark Session did not reach idle status in time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark

I am running a long jupyter notebook on pyspark AWS. I have encountered a strange behavior so that whenever I stop a running cell and rerun it again I got an error similar to:
`An error was encountered: Session 111 did not reach idle status in time. Current status is busy`, and I need to restart the kernet and rerun from the first cell which is too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

this is what happens when a kernel is stopped, instead of stopping it properly.
seems like the UI and the kernel aren't connected together anymore